# React Native E2E w/ Detox error: "Failed to run application on the device"

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I have a starter app created with React Native CLI on a Mac, added Detox and am trying to run the sample tests. I get this error (newlines added for easier reading):

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/detox -c android test
detox[37289] INFO:  [test.js] configuration="android" reportSpecs=true readOnlyEmu=false 
    useCustomLogger=true forceAdbInstall=false DETOX_START_TIMESTAMP=1591313397594 
    node_modules/.bin/jest --config e2e/config.json '--testNamePattern=^((?!:ios:).)*$' -- 
    maxWorkers 1 android test
detox[37290] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:62332...
detox[37290] ERROR: [DetoxExportWrapper.js/DETOX_INIT_ERROR] 
 DetoxRuntimeError: Failed to run application on the device

HINT: Most likely, your tests have timed out and called detox.cleanup() while it was 
waiting for "ready" message (over WebSocket) from the instrumentation process.
```

When it runs, the emulator starts but the app does not.

The app runs fine separate from E2E tests, through React Native CLI.

**`.detoxrc.json`**

```
{
  "testRunner": "jest",
  "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
  "configurations": {
    "android": {
      "type": "android.emulator",
      "binaryPath": "android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk",
      "build": "cd android; ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBiuldType=debug; cd -",
      "device": {
        "avdName": "Pixel_3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Environment:

```
Detox: 16.7.0
React Native: 0.62.2
Node: v12.17.0
Device: Pixel 3, x86, API 29, Android 10
OS: MacOS 10.15.4
Test-runner: Jest
Android Studio: 3.6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I missed a few steps on the second page of getting started instructions specific to Android.

https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Introduction.Android.md